# What gods or forms are worshipped/revered in Sri Vaishnavam?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

I would like a comprehensive list of who is worshipped in Sri Vaishnavam. It would be really nice if it included many of Sri Vishnu's form.